# R: Regress all variables that match certain pattern

Tags: regex, r

Is there a way in R to add all variables into a regression that match a certain pattern?  For example, I have a bunch of variables in my dataset that correspond to holidays with the prefix h_ and I have other variables with other prefixes such as a_

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
lm(homicide ~ w_* + a_*, data= df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To programmatically construct a formula, have a look at `reformulate()`.

Here's an example that uses `grep()` to find all variables that begin with a `"d"` and then uses `reformulate()` to plug them in as the regressor variables on the RHS of a formula object.

```
vv <- grep("^d.*", names(mtcars), value=TRUE)
ff <- reformulate(termlabels=vv, response="mpg")
lm(ff, data=mtcars)
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = ff, data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         disp         drat  
#    21.84488     -0.03569      1.80203
```

Answer (score 0):

A string can be turned into a formula.

```
data(iris)

fmla <- as.formula(paste("Species ~", 
               paste(grep("Width", names(iris), value = TRUE), collapse = " + ")))

glm(fmla, data = iris, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```